# limit maximum input to the database php mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

how can i limit the maximum number of rows in mysql. For example, if the number of grade 4, section 1 students is 30 or over, the user cannot add another student.

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: If you are using PHP use count function then check if students are 30 or over show error instead of insertion!!!

Comment: Just implement this in your application logic.  I would assume you would need to detect such cases and message the user anyhow, so why enforce it in the database? I wouldn't even give the option to insert in the app if the class size is already at the max.

Answer (score 1):

first count the rows of the given conditions

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) as cnt FROM `your_table` WHERE grade='4' AND section='1'");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);

if($row['cnt']<30)
{
     // insert student
}
else
{
     // not to insert student
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER trigger1
BEFORE INSERT
ON table1
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO @cnt FROM table1;
  IF @cnt > 30 THEN
    /**raise an error**/
  END IF;
END
$$

DELIMITER ;
```